# JQuery - arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, dictionary

how can I create map to send it like post-data, using ajax? For exmaple, I has an iterator **each** function, where I should do something like:

```
var map = [];
...each(function() {
map[ $(this).key() ] = $(this).val();
});
```

Or what another synax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to submit form data through ajax, take a look at [serialize()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize)

Answer (score 0):

You would essentially be mimicking jQuery's serialize() function:

```
var serialized = [], str;
$.each('#youritem', function(key, val) {
    serialized.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(val));
}); 

// will contain your $_GET string
str = serialized.join('&')
```